# Redux and Typescript "Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'string[]'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to fetch data in redux and return a part of them, not all of it, but Typescript tells me that "Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'string[]'". I tried to see it it has to do with the interface or the initialState but cannot find a solid answer.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useAppDispatch } from './hooks';


export interface MealState {
  meal: string[],
  input: string,
  favorites: string[],
  categories: string[],
}

const initialState: MealState = {
  meal: [],
  input: '',
  favorites: [],
  categories: [],
};

const mealReducer = createSlice({
  name: 'meal',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // ADD INPUT
    addInput: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.input = action.payload
    },

  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getMeal.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.meal = action.payload;
    });
  }

});

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------


export default mealReducer.reducer

// Actions
export const {
  addInput,
  addFavorites,
} = mealReducer.actions;



export const getMeal = createAsyncThunk(
  'meal/getMeal',
  async (search: string) => {
    const response = await axios.get<string[]>(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${search}`);
    return response.data.meals; // <== this create the problem, I can only return response.data
  }
);
```

I can work with response.data, but then the problem is the same when I use

```
  const list = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.meal.meal.meals)
```

since meals does not exist in the first place i will get "Property 'meals' does not exist on type 'string[]'"

Comment: There is no property called `meals` defined anywhere in your code, so I would not expect it to be found. Perhaps if the response from the webserver was a JSON object with a `meals` property, you'd get further, but you are requesting an array of strings as the axios response (`get<string[]>`), so that's what you'll get ... and obviously string arrays do not contain any property called `meals`. Also, you might get a better response here if you show what the result from the `axios.get` request looks like.

Comment: I've just tried that URL myself ... you probably want to define a type called e.g. MealSearchResults (which matches the format of the data you're receiving) and use that as the generic parameter to `axios.get`

Comment: I just changed the ```(get<string[]>)``` for ```(get<any>)``` and it works, I start to understand a little bit better, thank you

Comment: even if I had suggest `(get<any>)` in my answer, but **this is not a good practice !**, I suggested it just to avoid the error but once you understand what is the type of your `response` change `<any>` to this type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `return` value of your function `getMeal` is what you will get as value for the `meal` attribute of your `state`, and since

```
meal: string[]
```

the `getMeal` function should return data of type `string[]` which is not the case here according to the error you got

what I suggest is :

- console.log and understand better what you are getting as response from the request

  create const myMeal from the response

  return it

```
async (search: string) => {
   const response = await axios.get<any>(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${search}`);
   console.log(response.data);
   const myMeal: string[] = // I don't know how your response.data looks like but myMeal should be of type string[]
   return myMeal;
  }
```